# Exim Mysql forwarding equivalent to postfix's mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf

Tags: mysql, email, forward, postfix-mta, exim

So I'm new to figuring out mail servers and configurations and trying to figure some of this information out. We are currently on a server that is using postfix and have a mysql database that has a simple table of an incoming email and the forward email. We are using postfix's config file to forward using the mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf file formatted like below.

user = mailuser
password = mypassword    <-- use your own database password here
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mailserver
query = SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source='%s'

Which thus behaves as follow. If my table has values of source=joe@domain.com, destination=joe@gmail.com. If anyone sends an email to joe@domain.com it forwards it and attachments to joe@gmail.com

I'm looking to do the same thing on an Exim mail server, but not finding an easy source. Any help or guidance for the easiest and/or similar configuration to use our current table would be great.

Answer (score -1):

`postfixadmin` is the web-UI for the database suitable for postfix as well as for exim (with some restrictions). Aliasing/forwardimg is present too. There is lot of howtos about configuring `exim` managed with `postfixadmin`.

Comment: Very useless if don't provide any examples